# Excel VBA - How to copy or move columns to a single row?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy columns to a single row by using a macro. The values under columns 1-6 should go to the next empty line in A. I want to do this with a macro as i have hundreds & thousands of columns to be moved to a single row. I did try the macro recorder, but can't really achieve what i want

[image: The expected result]

I tried the following, but it keeps replacing the value instead of adding below it:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim x As Integer
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 3) <> ""
DoEvents
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 4)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 5)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 6)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 7)
Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 8)
Sheet1.Range("C2:H2").Clear
Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Post what you've tried. You're more likely to get help if you show that you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the code i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looping through the rows of column C and find the last used column in each column to transpose its values to column A:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CollectRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRowA As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    Const FirstCol As Long = 3 'column C is the first column with data

    Dim LastRowC As Long
    LastRowC = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FirstCol).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in col A

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRowC 'run from row 2 to last row in column C
        LastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in col A
        LastCol = ws.Cells(iRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column in current row

        'copy and transpose values
        ws.Cells(LastRowA, "A").Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=LastCol - FirstCol + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Cells(iRow, FirstCol).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol - FirstCol + 1).Value)
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: This works as i wanted it to. Thanks for the great sharing as well. I understand how it works now.